# sed/awk Capitallize everything between patterns and lowercase small words

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

I did find a way to capitalize the whole document, with both `sed` and `awk`, but how to do it, if I want to convert everything inside patterns from `CAPS LOCK` to `Capital`?

For example, I have an HTML file, and everything (multiple occurrences) between `<b>` and `</b>` has to be converted from `TITLE` to `Title`, and if possible making small words (1 ~ 2 letters) in lowercase.

From This:

```
<div id="1">
<div class="p"><b>THIS IS A RANDOM TITLE</b></div>
<table class="hugetable">
...
</table>
<div class="p"><b>THIS IS ANOTHER RANDOM TITLE</b></div>
<table class="hugetable">
...
</table>
...
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="1">
<div class="p"><b>This is a Random Title</b></div>
<table class="hugetable">
...
</table>
<div class="p"><b>This is Another Random Title</b></div>
<table class="hugetable">
...
</table>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most beautiful solution but I think it works:

```
sed -r -e '/<b>/ {s/( .)([^ ]*)/\1\L\2/g}' -e 's/<b>(.)/<b>\u\1/' -e '/<b>/ {s/(\b.{1,2}\b)/\L\1/g}' data
```

Explanation:

- 1st expression (`-e`): If a line contains `<b>`:

  - Then for each word which has a space in front of it, keep the space and the first (already capitalized) character (`\1`) and then convert all the following characters of the word to lower case (`\L\2`)
- 2nd expression (`-e`): The first word after `<b>` is still uncapitalized, so select the first character after the bold tag `<b>(.)` and replace it uppercased `<b>\u\1`
- 3rd expression (`-e`): Again if a line contains `<b>`:

  - Then select words of 1 or 2 characters in length `\b.{1,2}\b` and replace them lowercased `\L\1`

Comment: It really works, but what about the small words, for example `"a"`, `"an"`, `"of"` (util 2  characters), any way of making sed ignore them?

Comment: @ghaschel it is not getting any prettier, but I added the decapitalization of 1/2-character words.